# Compare two columns of factors from two data frame, get the entries exist in both data frame in r

Tags: r, compare

I have two data frames:

**df1**

```
vehicle  speed  time
a         23     234
b         34     421
d         45     290
```

**df2**

```
vehicle  speed  time
a         29     215
b         54     450
c         45     21
f         40     367
```

Both vehicle columns are factors. I want to find the common vehicles and add the corresponding df2$time to df1, name it as time.2.

The output I want:

**df1**

```
vehicle  speed  time    time.2
a         23     234     215
b         34     421     450
```

I tried:

```
df1 <- df1[df1$vehicle %in% df2$vehicle, ]
df2 <- df2[df2$vehicle %in% df1$vehicle, ]
df1 <- cbind(df1, time.2 = df2$time)
```

But after the first two commands, both df1 and df2 have 0 rows inside. I have tried before, when I use another data frame to compare the vehicle with df1, it works. I don't why df2 doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `as.character` then `merge`

Comment: I tried this, does not work.

Comment: @GaryWeissman probably has teh right idea, but `match` is another possibility, `df2[match(df1$vehicle, df2$vehicle, 0L), 'time']` will get you your `time.2`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1,
           df2 %>%
             select(-speed) %>%
             rename(time.2 = time) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `merge()` function:

```
df1$vehicle <- as.character(df1$vehicle)
df2$vehicle <- as.character(df2$vehicle)
df <- merge(df1, df2, by="vehicle")
df <- df[, c("vehicle.x", "speed.x", "time.x", "time.y")]
```

Comment: I edit the question to make it more similar to my problem. The number of rows are not the same of these two data frames. Then how to proceed?

Comment: What is the relation between the two tables then?

Comment: Data from different periods. I want the data of vehicles exist in both periods, then make further inference.

Comment: Mr. Big, you need to define a precise _relation_ between the two data frames.  Can you do this?

Comment: The relation is there are common vehicles exist in both data frames. I want compare two data frames based on vehicles, keep the records of common vehicles, then combine df2$time with df1. That's what i expected to see.

Comment: My answer should be working for you, since you told us you want to join on the vehicle column.

Comment: I tried, but it returns a data frame with no data inside, but the new column from df2 do has been added to df. I don't know why? Please help.

Comment: Maybe the vehicle in df2 has different type or something different inside? Cause, when I display the df1$vehicle, it shows a single list(n by one) of vehicle names in the console, while df2$vehicle returns the vehicle names in a matrix form(m by p). I don't know if this indicates df1$vehicle is differently recognized in r compared with df2$vehicle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92089/discussion-between-white-big-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I found the answer. When I display the element of df1$vehicle, the vehicle name is changed, like "103X(a lot of white space after 'X')", while in df2$vehicle, it is "103X". That's  the reason, why the display looks abnormal, cause there are so may space behind the vehicle name! I use gsub( ) to replace the  "\\s" with "". Solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @White.Big You should post your own solution then.

Comment: I have deleted the last question about this. I thought it might be redundant at some point, though I want help urgently.